# Does my iPhone use up my MacBook Pro battery when it is plugged in?

Tags: iphone, battery

I have had a Macbook Pro 2019 for two years and I almost always use it plugged to the AC. Let's say I let it fully run out of battery power roughly once a week, just as I used to do with my former MacBook Pro.
I have noticed, though, that its battery lifespan has reduced at a much quicker rate than its predecessor's, which seems strange to me. Then I have realised that, contrary to my former MacBook, I very often use my iPhone as a USB hotspot, because my present house has neither an ethernet nor a Wi-Fi connection .
Therefore, I am wondering if my iPhone is draining the battery of my MacBook when plugged into it also if the computer is running on AC. From the system information dialogue, it seems that this is not happening, but my observation on the battery quicker drainage after a comparable usage time stays...
Does anybody know the answer ? And, if this is actually the case, is there a way to tweak the settings so that the iPhone stops using the MacBook's battery power ?

Thanks everybody in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Battery lifespan and usage is a complex topic and may things factor into it.

> I am wondering if my iPhone is draining the battery of my MacBook when plugged into it also if the computer is running on AC

The most likely answer is **no**.
However, depending on what wall adapter you are using and what you are doing with your MacBook it *may* need the battery. Say your wall adapter only provides 60Watts, your MacBook uses 80W and you also plug in your phone (usually USB gives 5W). Thats 25W more than what you are getting from the wall. It has to come from the battery. Yet, this should be indicated by the MacBook.

So, depending on the wall adapter the answer may actually be yes. In that case your battery will drain, although connected to an outlet.

If I understand you correctly though, the problem is actually a decreased battery capacity. It would be interesting to see exact numbers, e.g. from coconut battery. Battery lifespan *mostly* (but there are many other factors) depends on the temperature it has been used in. I.e. when you always push your MBP to its limits and temperatures rise for a long period the battery will be in a worse state if you used the same amount of cycles in cooler conditions.

Many people claim its also better to *not* let the battery fully drain, however, [the effect seems to be less devastating as some state](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/does-fully-discharging-a-lithium-based-battery-reduce-its-lifespan). Yet, it seems measurable and therefore I try to not go down to 0% when possible,

Apples tips on how to maximize battery life: https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, I'll look deeper into the issue. Likely, the fact that the first task I have bought this MacBook for was pushing it to its limits for several months may have had an impact on subsequent residual battery capacity.